# How can I bind dict to Prepared Cassandra Statement in Python?

Tags: python, cassandra, cassandra-driver

How can I pass dict and query parameters?

I can do such code.

```
prepared = session.prepare('select name from task where id = ?;')
bound = prepared.bind([1])
session.execute(bound)
```

How can I use dict as parameters and what will be query syntax?

This not works:

```
prepared = session.prepare('select name from task where id = %(id)s;')
bound = prepared.bind({"id": 1})
session.execute(bound)
```

Can you help with this basic code - it looks that it is possible but I do not know valid query syntax?

Answer (score 5):

```
query = """
        INSERT INTO table_name (
            field_1,
            field_2
        ) VALUES (?, ?)
"""
cql_session.prepare(query).bind({'field_1': 'foo', 'field_2': 'bar'})
```

this works for us.

[Docs](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/query.html#cassandra.query.BoundStatement.bind) says that

> *bind(values)*
>
> Binds a sequence of values for the prepared statement parameters and returns this instance. Note that values must be:
>
> - a sequence, even if you are only binding one value, or
> - **a dict that relates 1-to-1 between dict keys and columns**

Comment: It looks very strange for me ':field1' can be good syntax but '?'. Are you sure that is not random effect since dict is not ordered but order can fit by lucky?

Comment: I guess it parses query and takes columns names, then takes value from dict by this column name and replace '?' with it. Anyway this is what docs tells us - *a dict that relates 1-to-1 between dict keys and columns*

Comment: I will test it since look like awesome syntax.